# Application of the Symbol datatype

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I tried to figure out myself but without any success. I am wondering if there is a valid application for the immutable datatype, [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol).

Does anyone know any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage of Symbols is that they are unique and cannot collide with another instance (assuming you're not using the global symbol registry). This is important for modularization, object proxies and forward-compatible extension of library objects.

Consider the following scenario: You code for a browser. You modify the prototype of, let's say HTMLElement, adding a new property for your library.
Now the whatwg/w3c come along and add an identically-named property to the standard. Suddenly your library is in conflict with the web standards.

Similar things happen when you subclass library methods. Import a new version of the library and it suddenly might have new methods that collide with yours.

This doesn't happen with symbols because you first instantiate a new, custom, local symbol that cannot collide with anyone else's symbols. Then you can use that as key that won't collide with any 3rd party code.

With modules you can simply export the module's symbols as constants, making them accessible to other modules, but only through proper, module-based namespacing, again avoiding collisions.

Classes can also use them to signal compliance with certain interfaces (since javascript has no multiple inheritance or interfaces), like [Symbol.iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/The_Iterator_protocol#The_.22iterable.22_protocol) does without risking name collisions or having to compromise on its own method names.

Additionally they can also be used as function arguments to avoid magic string constants which can be especially hazardous when they are mixed with regular string processing in the same argument. Not to mention that an undeclared symbol (normally imported as a constant) may lead to more predictable errors than an unknown string being passed in and simply falling through the special-casing inside the method.

They might also offer a performance advantage since comparing to a symbol basically is a O(1) pointer comparison instead of a string comparison. At least in cases where the compiler can't infer that string constants are identical.

Comment: It was also originally supposed to provide private methods, but the actual implementation is not that much private. I personally prefer [WeakMaps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) for that.